# Mac OSX server wiki 503 Error

Tags: mac-osx-server, osx-snow-leopard

I have a Snow Leopard server running in my localhost, and I activated the web service in it. Web Service is not used other than hosting default collaboration tools of the server.

I have only one site which has * as IP and Wiki web service is turned on under this server. When I visit the IP address of the server, I am welcomed with the homepage that presents available services (i.e., my page, wikis, blogs).

When I click on any of these services, I get:

```
Service unavailable!

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity                 problems. Please try again later.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 503
```

Apache error log: http://pastebin.com/yb1fHVb2

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: These lines:`[Tue Mar 25 08:22:24 2014] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8171 (*) failed
[Tue Mar 25 08:23:15 2014] [error] (61)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8087 (127.0.0.1) failed` seem to be the culprit here.

Comment: @vautee any idea why it is refusing the connection while it allows me to connect to the homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the wikid's log file was not created which I noticed in the ServerAdmin.app >> Web >> Sites >> Logs. In order to create the log:

```
cd /Library/logs
sudo mkdir wikid
sudo chown teamsserver:teamsserver wikid
sudo chmod 775 wikid
```

Finally, restart the web service.